# Can you use batteries to power a device that uses a plug?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

Can you use batteries to power a device?
I have multiple 1.5V batteries, there is a way to tie them together and power a device that uses a plug power supply?

Can I cut the plug and connect it to the batteries that added together have (6V) and the device uses 6V?

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the "device with a plug" ? What voltage and current does it require ? What kind of 1.5V batteries ?

Comment: remote control batteries and calculators ,
the device uses 6v

Comment: I live in a place where the power goes out, I would like to use batteries to power the device while there is no power. I know a generator does this, but I want to know if I can do it with batteries.

Comment: Better to buy a matching plug than cut the original cable.

Comment: yes you can if the 6V is regulated and protected

Comment: @molo32_1, you need to improve your question a lot. Are you asking about a mains plug or replacing a 6 V DC  wall wart with a set of batteries? Please [edit] your question to clarify ...

Comment: Plug is the cord that exits the device to connect to the electrical outlet.

Comment: Why don't you just tell us *what* "the device" is? Make, model...

Comment: If you want to just hook it up directly to a battery, it depends heavily on the device in question. If you don't mind something in between, use an inverter.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> Plug is the cord that exits the device to connect to the electrical outlet.

No, you can't cut the plug off and use batteries.

- You mains power is AC (alternating current and voltage) and relatively high (120 or 230 V).
- Your battery is DC and low voltage.

Comment: If the device is powered by a ‘wall wart’ plug-top power supply that outputs 6V to the device itself (and it appears from the OP that this is the case) then a 6V Battery supply could be used.  For NiMH cells this would call for five in series, or for alkaline cells you’d need four.  Power is often delivered via a 2.1mm DC jack, and the inner conductor is almost always positive.

Comment: @Frog, the OP has been asked to clarify and only added an illustration to indicate that s/he intents to cut the plug off a mains powered device and connect the mains cable to batteries.

Comment: Yes it's not entirely clear whether the OP knows that the device can run on 6V or hopes that it can.

Answer (score 0):

Many appliances powered by DC plugs can be powered from batteries instead.

First you need to determine the power requirements of the device.

6V is a good start, but you need to know how close to 6V it needs to be for proper operation?

How much current does the device need?

It may be that a battery pack consisting of several AA cells can power your device. It may be that a regulator is needed between the battery pack and the device to condition the supply to be exactly 6V (because batteries aren't precise voltage sources (except NiMh which are fairly presice 1.2V sources))